# Auto fetch command for ftp over ipv6

Tags: unix, ftp, ipv6

I have been trying to execute an auto-fetch url for a ftp server over ipv6.

user@freebsd10# ftp ftp://[2001:db8:0:1::132]/abc.conf 
ftp: No match.

As per ftp man page:
When specifying IPv6 numeric addresses in a URL, you need to surround the
address in  square brackets.  E.g.: ``ftp://[::1]:21/''.  This is because
colons are
 used in IPv6 numeric address as well as being the separator
for the port number

My server is up and running.
if I use below method it works fine.

user@freebsd10# cat > /var/tmp/tftpargs 
open 2001:db8:0:1::132 
ftp 
get abc.conf 
bye 

user@freebsd10# ftp < /var/tmp/tftpargs 
Connected to 2001:db8:0:1::132.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Name (2001:db8:0:1::132:root): 230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
local: abc.conf remote: abc.conf
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||31308|).
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for abc.conf (13913 bytes).
  0% |                                   |     0        0.00 KiB/s 
   --:--100% |***********************************| 13913       19.36 MiB/s 
   00:00 ETA
226 Transfer complete.
13913 bytes received in 00:00 (10.84 MiB/s)
221 Goodbye.

For ipv4, I am able to do both.
user@freebsd10# ftp ftp:// 5.5.5.2 /abc.conf 
Connected to 5.5.5.2.
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files
.
200 Switching to Binary mode.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for abc.conf (13913 bytes).
221 Goodbye.

Please let me know what is the correct way to do an auto-fetch for ftp over ipv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're using tcsh and it's complaining that your glob through [] does not match any files. Try quoting the url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Quoting the url worked.